# How to speed up the scroll speed of background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I want to achieve a simple parallax effect where the background image has to scroll faster than the elements above it. How can I achieve this with JQuery or using javascript?

Comment: greensock is a nice library for this as it utilizes css (gpu) under the hood. its used in huge websites for that such as google's product promo pages and so many more sites. its awesome.

Comment: Its a great library. But I couldn't figure out which plugin to use.

Comment: you could mimic what i did at preview.zipstory.com  just view source

Comment: i used a tween library which uses greensock

Comment: thank you for your help Jason.

Answer (score 0):

Get the current position of page scroll and multiply it by your favorite rate. Then change the position of background to result number:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var yOffset;  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
      yOffset=$(window).scrollTop()*10;
      $("body").css('background-position', '0px '+-yOffset+'px');
      })
})
```

```css
body{
  background:url('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
  height:4000px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: This does work but its very slow. Its better to utilize the GPU through css transforms. You can do this with JavaScript. You'll get up votes if you change your answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I don't know about GPU utilization.

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/